# How to enable editing combo in Grid grouping control's cell who has child table

Tags: c#-4.0, syncfusion

I am developing an windows application using syncfusion's grid grouping control(ggc). In ggc i have two columns. In that one column is of combobox type. When I expand this combo one grid is shown. Currently in that combo i can write only one character but i want to write multiple characters as we write in normal combo box.
Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownStyle of ComboBox can be set to Editable in order to enter contents in cell.

Here is the code that will achieve the behavior:

```
this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[1].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell.CellType = "CheckBox";
GridTableCellStyleInfo style = this.gridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns["Col2"].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell;
style.CellType = "GridListControl";
style.DropDownStyle = GridDropDownStyle.Editable ;
```

I hope this will resolve the issue.